# Failing test is showing as passed

Tags: apex, unit-test, exception, failing-tests, null-pointer

In Debug Logs I can see a `System.NullPointerException` for the unit test that was just run, but on the Apex Test Execution page I see the test as passing. The error is not buried within the log details; it shows straight up as the Status for the log.

[image: exception in Debug Logs]

[image]

If it helps, the offending code is placed within a try-catch block in the unit test:

```
static void testmethod testEmails()
{
    // prep data

    // attempt to send email
    try 
    { 
        /* code that calls Messaging.sendEmail */ 
    }
    catch (EmailException e) 
    {
        // ignore if Single Emails aren't configured yet
        if (e.getMessage().contains('Single email must be enabled')) {}
    }
}
```

Any ideas why?!

Answer (score 1):

The test only fails if System.assert(false) is called (or other types, like assertEquals or assertNotEquals do not receive a matching condition), or if an unhandled exception occurs. Since the try-catch block handles the exception, the test is still considered passing. Normally, unless you're trying to unit test that an exception occurs, you should *not* be using try-catch in your unit test code.

## Expected Success

Here, we don't try to catch an exception. If we get an exception, it will cause the unit test to fail automatically. We don't need to do anything special.

```
@isTest static void test() {
    MyClass.myFunction(params);
}
```

## Expected Failure

When we expect a failure in the form of an exception, use a try-catch, but *only* for the exception we expect to get (e.g. a QueryException or NullPointerException). Allow all other exceptions to remain unhandled, so they cause unexpected failures to fail the unit test.

```
@isTest static void test() {
    try {
        MyClass.myFunction(params);
        System.assert(false, 'Should not reach this line of code.');
    } catch(ExpectedException e) {
        // Good, we got the exception we expected
    }
}
```

You should generally not try to catch Exception directly, as it is the parent of all exceptions. This is true even outside of unit testing. A developer should catch only exceptions they expect; if they come across another type of exception, allowing the exception to escape will let the developer be notified of a situation they didn't expect.

Comment: Good information, but the catch in the question is catch(EmailException) which would not catch a NullPointerException.

Comment: @KeithC The unit test wasn't included in the original question, but from the wording, I presumed that the unit-test itself contains the catch(Exception) which was then silently ignored.

Comment: Appreciate the reply. As @KeithC mentioned the exception being caught in the unit test is only `EmailException`, not the generic `Exception`. Granted I should have added an else-statement that threw the error, but I'm not sure if my question is answered yet.

Comment: I'm afraid we don't have enough code to answer the question. I know I'm right, but the try-catch could be anywhere. You need to understand the entire flow. Start from the line of code where NPE appears and read backwards. You'll find a try-catch somewhere. Afterwards, find which exceptions it catches.

Comment: I may not have been clear, but the NPE is not buried in the log details. It shows up straight under the Status column on the Debug Log page. If it was buried then sure, I could conclude along the same lines.

Comment: @user1936026 Either you're reading the wrong log, *or* there's a defect with the system. It shouldn't be possible to have a status other than success and have a unit test pass. I've been writing them since they were nothing more than a pilot program, and I don't think I've ever seen that happen before. ...but I *have* read the wrong logs before. It was rather stupid when I figured out it was my own mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the outermost error is actually an `EmailException`, a discovery that only became apparent after running the logs through the LMA app. So by virtue of not having an else-statement in my catch-block the error was getting eaten.

BUT, I still do not understand why the error shows up in Debug Logs as the Status for my log! If the error was "meant" to be eaten then it should not show up as the Status either.